# Efficient field mapping with 1000s of case statements with REGEX patterns

Tags: sql, regex, etl

I have a large table (30B+ rows) where based on values in 2 fields, I want to determine the vendor's name through a regular expression.  There are over 1,000 vendors each with at least one REGEX to identify it.

Currently, I use a massive SQL case statement but it takes a lot of time & resources, if at all.  (RedShift & Snowflake handles it, Google BigQuery does not.)

Question: Is there another approach to this problem, possibly prior to loading into the database?

Comment: Are you persisting the results of the match to someplace so it doesn't need to be run again on that row?

Comment: "*prior to loading into the database*" - Well streaming the data into a program/script that processes the data in parallel would likely be the most performant way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is not of top concern, you could put "regexp to vendor" mapping in a table, and perform the conversion inside a database, using a join / cartesian product. Note: it probably will be slow-ish with any database.

If you want top performance, you might want to invest and write a custom program to do it. There are libraries that can help matching very many regexps at the same time, e.g. [lightgrep](https://github.com/strozfriedberg/liblightgrep) or [hyperscan](https://github.com/intel/hyperscan). Lightrep even has a Python API that might make it easier.

Comment: Thank you!  You gave me great food for thought.